# ContentNegotiatingViewResolver trying to return [application/x-msdownload] when an email is inserted in the URL

Tags: spring, web-services

I'm creating a REST webservice, based on Spring/Spring integration. I'm using a `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in order to allow XML and JSON responses from my webservice.

Recently, I've added a new parameter in my URL that is referring to an email. The service is broken as soon as I'm passing the email value in the parameters.

The following request is failing:

```
> POST /statefull/f/initiateEnrollment/otherId/-/firstName/Omar/middleName/-/lastName/BELKHODJA/address1/line1/address2/-/address3/-/city/Ariana/postalCode/2080/country/Tunisia/mobile/52841950/birthDate/14-01-1980/email/omar@gmail.com?format=json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
```

Whereas the following one is succeeding:

```
> POST /statefull/f/initiateEnrollment/otherId/-/firstName/Omar/middleName/-/lastName/BELKHODJA/address1/line1/address2/-/address3/-/city/Ariana/postalCode/2080/country/Tunisia/mobile/52841950/birthDate/14-01-1980/email/omar@gmail?format=json HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
```

The only difference is that I have removed the `.com` from the email value.

The failing case shows the following traces:

```
2015-04-10 20:18:29,007 DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:  342 - Requested media types are [application/x-msdownload] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2015-04-10 20:18:29,008 DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:  312 - No acceptable view found; returning null
2015-04-10 20:18:29,008 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:  989 - Could not complete request
```

Whereas the succeeding case shows:

```
2015-04-10 20:21:57,294 DEBUG ParameterContentNegotiationStrategy:   67 - Requested media type is 'application/json' (based on parameter 'format'='json')
2015-04-10 20:21:57,294 DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:  342 - Requested media types are [application/json] based on Accept header types and producible media types [*/*])
2015-04-10 20:21:57,294 DEBUG ContentNegotiatingViewResolver:  417 - Returning [com.transacteleurope.rest.json.view.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView: name 'com.transacteleurope.rest.json.view.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView#51471d4d'] based on requested media type 'application/json'
```

My spring configuration is should be forcing a resolution based on the format parameter (see below):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/xml"/>
            <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
            <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
            <property name="mediaTypes">
                <map>
                    <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="com.transacteleurope.rest.json.view.ExtendedMappingJacksonJsonView">
                <property name="objectMapper" ref="jaxbJacksonObjectMapper"/>
                <property name="updateContentLength" value="true"/>
            </bean>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg ref="restMarshaller"/>                    
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug in my code, or in Spring itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring considers anything behind the last dot as a file extension such as .json or .xml and truncate it . That is the issue here. If you want to ignore that do the following config and give it a try.

```
<bean id="handlerMapping"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
    <property name="contentNegotiationManager" ref="contentNegotiationManager"/>
    <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You probably identified the root cause. Now, for the fix, because I'm using Spring integration, and a HTTP inbound gateway, I have tried the following, without further success. `<bean id="org.springframework.web.servlet.config.viewControllerHandlerMapping"
          class="org.springframework.integration.http.inbound.IntegrationRequestMappingHandlerMapping">
        <property name="useSuffixPatternMatch" value="false"/>
    </bean>`. Any idea ?

Comment: @OmarBELKHODJA, Which version of spring are you on?

Comment: For Spring, I'm using 4.1.1.RELEASE. For Spring integration, 4.1.2.RELEASE.